# Building EAR and deploying on Weblogic 12c

Tags: java, maven, weblogic, ear

I'm trying to build an Application and package it as EAR file to deploy it on an Weblog server.
I created a Simple example here: https://github.com/PaulFinnE/myapptest

There is:

- a pom module for a simple servlet (some legacy stuff)
- a pom module for a html file (in future a Angual app)
- a pom module for a springboot application (but that's topic for a later)
- a pom module for building form these WARs an EAR file

Here the EAR build pug-in configuration:
full content: https://github.com/PaulFinnE/myapptest/blob/master/myapp-ear/pom.xml

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <displayName>MyAppY-Application-DisplayName</displayName>
                <description>MyAppY-Application-Description</description>
                <packagingIncludes>META-INF/**,*.war</packagingIncludes>
                <modules>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>local.example.myappy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>myapp-html-war</artifactId>
                        <contextRoot>myapp-html</contextRoot>
                    </webModule>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>local.example.myappy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>myapp-servlet-war</artifactId>
                        <contextRoot>myapp-servlet</contextRoot>
                    </webModule>
                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Here the html WAR build pug-in configuration:
full content: https://github.com/PaulFinnE/myapptest/blob/master/myapp-html-war/pom.xml

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>html/</directory>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Here the servlet WAR build pug-in configuration:
full content: https://github.com/PaulFinnE/myapptest/blob/master/myapp-servlet-war/pom.xml

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Both WARs are working as expected if I deploy them to a tomcat.

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp-servlet/hello
http://localhost:8080/myapp-html/index.html
```

but as I take the EAR file and deploy to weblogic I only get Not Found responses.

What do I miss to get the EAR working?

Note: I cant find anything in the Logs. The Server and the deployment status are fine. And other not build form myself EARs are working on that weblogic - but now my own do not.

Comment: Please show the full pom file...you should also keep the versions of the plugins consistent...not version 2.6 and 3.2.1 ...use only one version...best is to define all plugins in the parent pom of your project...

Comment: @khmarbaise: as the Poms are in sum quiet long I only extracted the interesting parts (I thought) but in the linked github repository is the full code (the minimal test project) - further more I now unified the versions of the maven plugins - but this changed nothing.

Comment: probably the port or context are not correct. It's easy to test by going to admin console under "testing" tab which will show the URL to root of the app

Comment: @devwebcl: thanks that's really great - I didn't know that. It was the key to the solution. I found the problem as a problem with the proxy (port mapping)